# How do I make a Django query that spans two tables?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to write a query who's result would be an `QuerySet` that has all the `title`s from from the Listing table associated with the max `value`s for each of the `bid`s in the `Bids` table.

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    starting_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.URLField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```
class Bids(models.Model):
    bid = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing_bids")
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
```

My ideal result would be something like `<QuerySet: ['('Cat': '3')......]>`

I have a Django query that will return a single value if you pass in a single title and I can get a list of titles, but I can't seem to pass that list of titles into it without getting an error.

`Bids.objects.all().filter(bid=Listing.objects.get(title=title)).aggregate(Max("value"))`

The following returns my desired result, but like I said, it is ugly and not using the power of Django queries...I don't think, but I could be wrong!

```
   test_list = []
   test = Bids.objects.all().values_list("bid_id", flat=True).distinct()
   for k in test:
        test_list.append(Bids.objects.all().filter(bid_id=k).aggregate(Max("value")))
   title_list = Listing.objects.all().values_list("title", flat=True)
   test_zip = dict(zip(title_list, test_list))
```

Any ideas? Happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `annotate` with `Max`:

```
Listing.objects.annotate(Max('listing_bids__value'))
```

And then each listing will have the attribute `listing_bids__value__max`

Comment: I'm unsure why but that returns a querylist with results from entry in Listing. <QuerySet [<Listing: Cat, 2.00, https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg>, <Listing: Raccoon, 5.00, https://curiodyssey.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/Mammals-Raccoon-square.jpg>, <Listing: Dog, 2.00, https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/03202400/Yellow-Labrador-Retriever.jpg>]> which is title, starting bid, image.

Comment: That's what you want, you can then iterate through it and get the `title` and `listing_bids__value__max` values

Comment: oh so in the template I can use {{title.listing_bids_value__max}}?

Comment: I assigned the query you wrote to a value, x, passed the value into the template and then tried {% for k in x%} {{k.listing_bids_value__max}} {% endfor %} it displayed nothing. Perhaps I don't get how to iterate over this particular query result?

Comment: That's because there should be two underscores between `bids` and `value`

Comment: There is in my code. Sorry for not producing it exactly. I will do a copy/paste: {% for k in x %}

<p>{{k.listing_bids_value__max}}</p>

{% endfor %}

Comment: There's still only one underscore between `bids` and `value`, try copying it instead

Comment: wow, thank you. I appreciate your patience. I can't believe I missed that detail. I will now go read annotate in the docs more closely to fully understand.